# Getting JSON data instead of frontend code

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, react-router

In my express backend, this is the order of my routers:
1.All the api routes (example: /notes)
2.The catch all route which sends back all the frontend code. (the react build folder)

On the client side I'm using React Router and all my routes are named differently from the api routes. (example: /me/notes)
However now when I go to the route /notes (my-website-name.com/notes), it sends me back the json data instead of the client side code.
Any way how I can always send back the frontend code instead of the json data?

Comment: Show us your code. Also your attempt in solving your bug.

Comment: Do you want both server and client on the same port even during development? If not they can be hosted on different ports instead for now. Then when online I'll post an answer later

Comment: If you are running React and Express in the same port then add `api` to the URL to differentiate. example for API(Express) - `my-website-name.com/api/notes` and UI(React) - `my-website-name.com/notes`. Adding API and version to the API endpoints is quite common.

Comment: @kunquan, I don't have a bug. This is expected behaviour. However, I'm new to development and wondering if this is alright or if there is a way to prevent this. 
(ie when the user types in the exact backend api (get) route in the urlbar, is there a way to direct them to a 404 page?)

Comment: @zS1L3NT this is in production. 
you can check it out yourself here: https://varma-task-app.herokuapp.com/notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API and Frontend are generally served from 2 different domain names in such cases.

And the host of the frontend application should return index.html on all the routes.

Example:

```
API: 
https://api.myapp.com/notes -> responds with notes list

Frontend: 

1. https://myapp.com -> returns index.html
2. https://myapp.com/<path> -> still returns index.html. 
React Router handles dynamic <path> when frontend app is loaded.
```

It really depends on the hosting how to make server requests to always respond with index.html, but I hope it gives you an idea.